# Equivalence of two binomial sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Earlier ([Coefficient of terms in expansions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2967281/coefficient-of-terms-in-expansions)) when $f(x)=(1+x+x^2)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{2n} A_k x^k$,
$A_k$ has been obtained as $$A_k=\sum_{j=0}^{k} {n\choose j} {j \choose k-j}.......(1)$$
Alternatively, we can obtain $A_k$ by noting that
$f(x)=(1-\omega x)^n (1-\omega^2x)^n$ and using the Cauchy product of two series as
$$A_k=(-\omega^2)^k \sum_{j=0}^{k} \omega^{-j} {n \choose j} {n \choose k-j}......(2)$$

Here $\omega$ is the cube root of unity.

The question here is: Can we prove the equivalence of these two expressions of $A_k$ as an identity, independently and directly(otherwise)?

**Edit:**  Both (1) and (2) can give $A_k$ only for $0\le k\le n$, for $k>n$ we use the particular feature of the series of $f(x)$ which is $A_{2n-k}=A_k$.

Comment: It may be pertinent to mention as well your [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4838147/305862) about the same polynomial. Who knows ? The technique mentionned in the interesting answer you have received might be useful for solving this issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The representation (2) of $A_k$ is for $0\leq k\leq n$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{A_k}&=[x^k]\left(1+x+x^2\right)^n=[x^k]\left(1-\omega x\right)^n\left(1-\omega^2 x\right)^n\\
&\color{blue}{=\left(-\omega^2\right)^k\sum_{j=0}^k(-\omega)^j\binom{n}{j}\binom{n}{k-j}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Due to symmetry of the polynomial we have $A_k = A_{2n-k}$ where $0\leq k\leq n$.

> We obtain from (1) as indicated in the comment by @JeanMarie
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{A_k}&\color{blue}{=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}\binom{n}{k-j}(-\omega)^j\left(-\omega^2\right)^{k-j}}\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{j=0}^{n}\binom{n}{j}(-\omega)^j[z^{k-j}]\left(1-\omega^2z\right)^n\tag{3}\\
> &=[z^k]\left(1-\omega^2z\right)^n\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}(-\omega z)^j\tag{4}\\
> &=[z^k]\left(1-\omega^2z\right)^n(1-\omega z)^n\tag{5}\\
> &=[z^k]\left(1-\left(\omega+\omega^2\right)z+\omega^3z^2\right)^n\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=[z^k]\left(1+z+z^2\right)^n}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}
> according to the claim.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we set the upper limit of the sum to $n$ which does not change anything, since $\binom{n}{k-j}=0$ if $j>k$ according to a *[common convention](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814429/the-definition-of-binomnr-considering-rn-is-allowed/3816456#3816456)*.
- In (3) we use the *coefficient of* operator to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ of a series. This way we can write $[z^k](1+z)^n=\binom{n}{k}$.
- In (4) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.
- In (5) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (6) we recall the following properties of the third root of unity $\omega=e^{2i\pi/3}=-1/2(1-i\sqrt{3})$: $\omega+\omega^2=-1$ and $\omega^3=1$.

Comment: Very nice, but a more direct proof is still desired.

Comment: Could you please see the Edit of my OP, I think that it needs to be mentioned necessarily. Please comment.

Comment: @ZAhmed: The edit is sound, since in your expression (1) we have that $\binom{n}{j}=0$ if $j>n$. So, your expressions (1) and (2) are valid for $0\leq k\leq n$ and due to symmetry we have $A_k=A_{2n-k}$.

Comment: Thanks for your concurrence.

Comment: @ZAhmed: You're welcome.